# nginx config for websockets (Actioncable)

Tags: nginx, websocket, actioncable

I am trying to set up nginx config to support Ruby's actioncable flavor of websockets, and I continue to get a 404 at the mounted path. The logs show:

```
Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: close, HTTP_UPGRADE: )
```

I am modifying config already set by my company's platform, and it looks like:

```
location / {
        # root location for static assets
        root /opt/app/public;

        # for uri's not found in public assets look for index.html, if doesn't exist fall back to @app
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html @app;
      }

      location @app {
          <% if !ENV['PROXY_HTTP_VERSION'].nil? && !ENV['PROXY_HTTP_VERSION'].empty? %>proxy_http_version <%= ENV["PROXY_HTTP_VERSION"] %>;<% end %> 
          proxy_pass http://app;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $reqstart;
          proxy_read_timeout <%= !ENV['NGINX_PROXY_READ_TIMEOUT_SECONDS'].nil? && !ENV['NGINX_PROXY_READ_TIMEOUT_SECONDS'].empty? ? ENV["NGINX_PROXY_READ_TIMEOUT_SECONDS"] : 60 %>;
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_request_buffering <%= (ENV['NGINX_DISABLE_PROXY_REQUEST_BUFFERING'] == 'true') ? 'off' : 'on' %>;
      }

        set $cable_location <% if !ENV['BASEPATH'].nil? && !ENV['BASEPATH'].empty? %><%= ENV["BASEPATH"] %>/<%= ENV["WEBSOCKET_ROUTE"] %>;<% else %>/<%= ENV["WEBSOCKET_ROUTE"] %>;<% end %>

        location $cable_location {
            <% if !ENV['PROXY_HTTP_VERSION'].nil? && !ENV['PROXY_HTTP_VERSION'].empty? %>proxy_http_version <%= ENV["PROXY_HTTP_VERSION"] %>;<% end %> 
            proxy_pass http://app;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $reqstart;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade "websocket";
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout <%= !ENV['NGINX_PROXY_READ_TIMEOUT_SECONDS'].nil? && !ENV['NGINX_PROXY_READ_TIMEOUT_SECONDS'].empty? ? ENV["NGINX_PROXY_READ_TIMEOUT_SECONDS"] : 60 %>;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_request_buffering <%= (ENV['NGINX_DISABLE_PROXY_REQUEST_BUFFERING'] == 'true') ? 'off' : 'on' %>;
        }
```

In the above, eventually setting websocket forwarding at all would be wrapped in an if-statement, but for testing it's not. What cable_location would look like is either `/basepath/websocket` or `/websocket` depending on what the env variables look like. Unit testing shows that cable_location is correctly set when the env variables exist. The basepath variable would come in such as `/basepath` and the websocket_route as `websocket`.

The above config looks correct from my google search, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.